# Why does one venue have 16 venue ids?

Tags: foursquare

All 16 of these venues have same name and same lat/lon.

In this case, their category is private residence, so that helps make a decision as to what to do with them and it turns out to not be a problem, but still, what's going on?  Is this something to worry about?

- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce1ef7b70bba1cd8e7574c4
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18e8e78ddf04db02cac98
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18eb7ffcf3704f4842682
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ebec4f6a35dd2fddb6c
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ec469136dcbb332eae6
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ec678ddf04dd72dac98
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ec77e2e236ac60e911b
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ec8f8cdb1f717549d12
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ec994c3b60c455577ea
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18eca825e721ec75c7c45
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ecb3644a093f4c65d9f
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ed9f8cdb1f75e549d12
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ee4ffcf3704fe852682
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ef3db125481d59242ce
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce18ef9aba88cfa690556d7
- https://foursquare.com/v/puamana-condos/4ce1ef4fc4f6a35d2f29de6c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all these venues were created by a single user on a single day back in December 2010. This was before we implemented more rigorous checking about existing duplicates before creating new venues, so it was probably a side effect of a poor connection / multiple creation attempts. Marking them as dupes and this should be cleaned up soon.

Because they're homes, they don't show up in normal "nearby" queries, which is why our SU community probably hadn't found them till now.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, and good to know.  See what I mean about SO as support forum though? I thought it was a legitimate question, and it was legitimate enough for you to actually look at it. But, it is so specific it gets 2 downvotes (I'm assuming that's the reason for downvotes).  Thanks for looking!